# Standardize XML file tag naming and then do work on the values

Tags: c++, xml, c++11

I'm working with a lot of XML files which each have their own naming convention:

Filea.xml

```
<entry>
<id>1</id>
<information>Testing</information>
<url>www.google.com</url>
</entry>
...
```

Fileb.xml

```
<entry>
<id>1</id>
<content>Testing</content>
<website>www.google.com</website>
</entry>
...
```

Filec.xml

```
<entry>
<id>1</id>
<data>Testing</data>
<url>www.google.com</url>
</entry>
...
```

In my code I use a map to define what tag contains what information, for example, for Fileb.xml:

```
const std::map<int,std::string> tagMap {
    {"id","id"}, 
    {"description","content"}
};
```

Then when I grab an XML node from my file, I loop through my tag map, which looks for the specified tag names and assignes them to the type of content they are.

```
for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
        // This aims to grab the content of the file tag and names it correctly based on it's content
        kv.first=eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
}
```

Depending on the tag that I have found, i.e "description", I want to do work on it. What is the right approach to this, should I have an if command for each tag I want to do work on, something like this?

```
if (kv.first="id") {
//Do something on the ID, i.e check if it is unique 
}

if (kv.first="description") {
// DO something on the description, i.e trim, validate
}
```

I'm a little concerned I am taking the wrong approach with this as:

1. I seem to define tags when when they match my naming convention
   `{"id","id"}`
2. Since in the real implementation I will be grabbing the content from about 10 XML tags, it seems wrong to do a loop for each tag I want to grab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-approach is fine (though you can use dispatch)
but you use map incorrectly (with looping and not with searching)

```
const std::map<int,std::string> tagMap {
    {"description","content"}
    // ...
    // no id -> id
};
string tagName = ... // get this from xml
if (tagMap.count(tagName))
    tagName = tagMap[tagName];

if (tagName == "id") { ... }
else if (tagName == "content") { ... }
```